# Is "assumation" a valid abstract noun of 'assume'?

Tags: word-request, formality, word-form, abstract-nouns

Is ['assumation'](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=assumation) a valid abstract noun of "assume" as:

> "You have to make an `assuming` that x is a real number"

sounds incorrect?

How formal is 'assumation'?

Comment: No. The word is assumption.  <<<--- that's the noun form.

Comment: @BillyKerr, I know that- but why are the question and answer downvoted? How are they unclear?

Comment: I don't know. I didn't downvote it. But perhaps because you linked to the Urban Dictionary website which is notorious for being inaccurate. It's better to use a proper dictionary website if you want to look up real words.  You can use [Oxford Learners Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/assumption?q=assumption) for free,

Comment: @BillyKerr, oh, but I linked "assumation" (in the question) to the website and not the answer. Yes, I did that on purpose because for a minute, I was confused, and when I looked it up, Urban Dictionary came up, so I linked it. Yes, thanks, but it didn't mention 'assumption' is abstract, so didn't link it.

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder It was likely downvoted because your question can be answered with a simple dictionary search, which makes it off-topic for this site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `assumation` is valid, not formal either.

`assuming` is not the abstract noun of 'assume'.

[`assumption`](https://www.answers.com/Q/Is_assumption_a_noun) is the correct abstract noun of 'assume'.

Comment: I don't know why **none** of the -dictionary sites mention it's an abstract noun. [Not even Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/assumption).